# What does .eof() for fstream in C++ does?

Tags: c++, fstream, eof

I am trying to count the number of lines in an excel sheet with the following code

```
line_count = 0;
while (!GBplaces.eof()){
    string Line;
    getline(GBplaces, Line);
    cout << Line << endl;
    line_count++;
    cout << line_count << endl;
}
```

There are only 101 lines on the excel sheet. However, with this code I get line_count = 102, as it appears that an extra blank line is counted. Why is that so? Does .eof() not make the line counting stop when the last line is reached?

Comment: No. It reports when you already tried to read past the end of the file.

Comment: The short answer is, you don't care about the end of the file, you care about whether a line is being read. That's what you should be checking.

Comment: e.g. `for (string Line; getline(GBplaces, Line);) { // use line }`